# Jquery load faile to load for second time

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am using the code bellow to reload a php file after 20 seconds inside a div, bu the problem is that after the first load on my target div it doesn't show anything.

any suggestions?

my code:

```
function getMyVideos(){
    $("#myvideos").load("http://www.mydomainz.com/myfile.php", function(){
        setTimeout(getMyVideos, 20000);
    });
}
$(document).ready(getMyVideos);
<div id="myvideos"></div>
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Have you checked for errors using dev tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use an anonymous function in your `setTimeout` function :

```
setTimeout(function(){getMyVideos();}, 20000);
```